# Yii2 dynamic connection to second database

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-model

I have a simple `select` in my View code. It represents list of cities and on my server there're several databases which are responsible for each city. I have my Model code and it takes `city_id`. Depends on it I want to connect to database and seek for needed data in it. I've added second database to my components like:

```
'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
'db2' => require(__DIR__ . '/db_login.php'),
```

and two files which returns database connection.

File 1:

```
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => $dsn,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password,
'charset' => 'utf8',
```

File 2:

```
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => $dsn,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password,
'charset' => 'utf8',
```

I want to change my database name somehow dynamically right after users' choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a call for  dbconnection

```
 $actual_dsn = 'your_dns_actual_value'
 $yourConnection = new \yii\db\Connection([
    'dsn' => $actual_dsn,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
 ]);
 $yourConnection->open();
```

eventually close the previous open connection

You can do this in your db_login.php depending of the application's needs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe :

```
if (choice =='a') {
'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php')
}
else {
'db2' => require(__DIR__ . '/db_login.php')
}
```